# Per-Interface rules for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

I have multiple network interfaces in a computer, and I would like to have individual firewall rules for them.

To achieve that, I put those rules in the three different profiles (Domain, Private, Public) and assign the profiles to the interfaces exactly like said in this question: [How do I assign Windows Firewall profiles to network interfaces from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/285159/how-do-i-assign-windows-firewall-profiles-to-network-interfaces-from-the-command)

This means, since per default every interface is assigned to every profile, I just deselect an interface at all profiles but the one it is to be assigned to.

When having done that, in the systray a warning appears that Windows Firewall would be deactivated (and that I should activate it).

Is that just wrong or have I missed anything?

**Edit**: I did nothing but to exclude all interfaces but one from the "private connection". The exact wording would not be of any use, since it is a non-English machine.

Comment: this might help re changing language(to english), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XKUBf_lBqM  he does it quite quickly like maybe 5min or less, then you an make your question clearer.  Also for troubleshooting it is best to know the exact words (in english).

Comment: I do not have Ultimate but Embedded Standard.

Comment: The fact your using an Embedded version of Windows 7 changes everything.  That it vital information you should include in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just how it works:

The profile is applied *only* if the network at an adapter matches it: When you are connected with a public network, the public profile gets applied *if the adapter is allowed in the public profile*. If it is not allowed, no profile gets applied, thus, the firewall is off for that network. So the warning is absolutely true.